# JavaScript function with Ajax request returns always the wrong value

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

I am a newbe in JavaScript and I want to create a website with Flask, JavaScript and Python. Currently I a have a problem. I call a JS function from my html page. That function creates an Ajax request and should return a value.

```
function getTime (idx) {
    const mo_time = 0;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/currdata',
        data: '',
        contentType: 'application/json'
    })
    .done( (data) => {  
        //console.log("success"); 
        mo_time = data["time"]; 
     })
    .fail( (data) => {

        //Data acquisition failure
        //console.log("error");
        mo_time = 0;
    });
    return (mo_time);    
}
```

The request is successfully but I always got 0 as return value. How can I put the data["time"] value into the mo_time variable?

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance you are trying to reassign the value of a `const mo_time`. Have you tried using `let`?

Answer (score 0):

@Michael
Constants are block-scoped. You can variables declared using the let keyword. The value of a constant can't be changed through reassignment

For scope please check this: [scope in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)

Please check these references.
[let var const](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-var-let-and-const-keywords-in-javascript/)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: Yes right. I also changed the declaration of my variable form const mo_time to var mo_time

Answer (score 0):

Yes I tried it. Meanwhile I found the solution. I have to add a async: false to the ajax request. The problem was the asynchronus call. I did the return while the request was not finished.

```
function getTime (idx) {
    var mo_time = 0;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/currdata',
        data: '',
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json'
    })
    .done( (data) => {  
        //console.log("success"); 
        mo_time = data["time"]; 
     })
    .fail( (data) => {

        //Data acquisition failure
        //console.log("error");
        mo_time = 0;
    });
    return (mo_time);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this case i prefer use the async/await approache with promises. Ajax request is asynchronous. When you call **getTime** method in a synchronous manner you get 0 value which follows from `const mo_time = 0;` in second line of code.

Try it:

```js
function getTime(idx) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/currdata',
            data: '',
            contentType: 'application/json'
        }).done((result) => resolve(result)).fail((error) => reject(error));
    });
}

async function main() {
    const data = await getTime(1);

    console.log(data['time']);
}

main();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise